# FFmpeg error loading shared libraries libx265.so.113

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, libx265

I recently installed libx265, I dont know what happened, but when I execute ffmpeg command I got this error :

```
 ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libx265.so.113: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I google it but got nothing specific about it.

I also executed this command: `ldd $(which ffmpeg)` and got the following output:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd147e7000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f1cea052000)
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f1ce9e30000)
libxcb-xfixes.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-xfixes.so.0 (0x00007f1ce9c27000)
libxcb-shape.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-shape.so.0 (0x00007f1ce9a23000)
libasound.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2 (0x00007f1ce9723000)
libx265.so.113 => not found
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f1ce9419000)
liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f1ce91f7000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f1ce8fdc000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f1ce8dbf000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f1ce89f6000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000559e03a1d000)
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f1ce87f1000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f1ce85eb000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f1ce83e3000)
```

Could someone help me?

Comment: The output is too long for a comment, how can I show it to you ? @LordNeckbeard

Comment: I added the requested info in the question @LordNeckbeard.

Comment: By distro, if you mean the OS, I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Where did you get this `ffmpeg` from and how did you install it? It is looking for libx265-113, but the 16.04 repo only provides libx265-79.

Comment: Well I got it from this repo [FFmpeg](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg) on github.

Comment: Can I use this libx265-79 with ffmpeg for encoding video sequence ? @LordNeckbeard

Comment: @LordNeckbeard for some reason It worked, Now I can use the Libx265 with ffmpeg. I already encode my file from (Y4M) to (H265) with the following command ` system(['ffmpeg -i ' videoNameIn, videoTypeIn, ' -s ' num2str(width),'x',num2str(height), ' -r ', num2str(frameRate), ' -c:v libx265 ',  videoNameOut, videoTypeOut]); ` I'm not sure if it the right command or not. Now I want to decode it to the original format(Y4M) but I'm not sure how to do it. Would you help me with it ?

Comment: So I must assume that you compiled libx265 and ffmpeg, then somehow deleted your compiled libx265. How did you fix the `libx265.so.113 => not found` issue?

Comment: Well I don't know exactly what happened, I was angry and I want to delete completely the ffmpeg package, I used this command `sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove ffmpeg` and multiple packages was deleted, after that bingo it worked.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs to super-user or video Q and A. Not related to programming.

Comment: Can I move it to super-user ? @OndraŽižka

Comment: I would move it but SO tells me this is too old to move. Perhaps you can just copy it there. Check http://video.stackexchange.com/ though where you have the experts on the matter

Comment: thanks @OndraŽižka.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem just. it It took half a day.

move the *libx265.so.151* to the system so *dir*.
the target is despend to you system

it will work  on my linux :

> cp libx265.so.151 /lib64/

from you ldd result,may be you should:

```
 cp libx265.so.151  /lib/
```